# How can I create a variable of different types depending on the outcome of an if statement in swift?

Tags: swift

My example is too complicated, so here is a simplified version of what I want to do:

```
    if someVariable {
        let thisVariable = 5
    } else {
        let thisVariable = "This is not a number"
    }

    print(thisVariable)
```

I am trying to use the same code on a variable regardless of its type, but I can't seem to find a way to cleanly do this since a variable declared in an if statement isn't global. I can't make it global though, because I can't declare its type outside the if statements. Is there a simple way to achieve the result I'm looking for? Thanks!

Comment: What will you use the global variable for? Just printing?

Comment: You could declare `thisVariable` as Any. But really you should ask yourself why you want to do this at all.

Comment: The best way to go about doing this depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve. Using a protocol or an enum is probably the way to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your simple example you can use a variable of type `Any`:

```
let thisVariable: Any
if someVariable {
    thisVariable = 5
} else {
    thisVariable = "This is not a number"
}
```

Or even:

```
let thisVariable: Any = someVariable ? 5 : "This is not a number"
```

But this may not be the best solution for your real, more complicated case.

Comment: Hmmm, perfect answer for what I asked, but I'm realizing it doesn't solve my problem like you said. In my original code, I am creating custom cells in a tableView, and I want them to pick which custom cell based on some criteria. I want to be able to write an if statement to test for the criteria, and then let cell = the type of custom cell I want. Problem is, my future code changes labels in the cells that have the same name for each custom cell. When I use type "Any," it just later says, "Value of type Any has no member "labelName."

Comment: Since you already have several answers to the question you asked, you should close this question by upvoting, accepting answers as you feel appropriate, then post a new question which deals with your real situation instead of a greatly simplified version.

Answer (score 1):

Swift is strongly typed, so the *type* of `thisVariable` must be known at compile time. You could wrap *instances* of other types in e.g. `Any`, or construct your own `enum` different type instances wrapper using cases with associated values.

```
enum TypeWrapper {
    case `string`(String)
    case `int`(Int)
}

func foo(_ someVariable: Bool) -> TypeWrapper {
    return someVariable ? .int(5) : .string("This is not a number")
}

let thisVariable = foo(true)  // .int(5)
let thatVariable = foo(false) // .string("This is not a number")
```

In the end, however, `thisVariable` is strongly typed as `TypeWrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

> Hmmm, perfect answer for what I asked, but I'm realizing it doesn't
>   solve my problem like you said. In my original code, I am creating
>   custom cells in a tableView, and I want them to pick which custom cell
>   based on some criteria. I want to be able to write an if statement to
>   test for the criteria, and then let cell = the type of custom cell I
>   want. Problem is, my future code changes labels in the cells that have
>   the same name for each custom cell. When I use type "Any," it just
>   later says, "Value of type Any has no member "labelName."

For your specific problem you could get away with three different ways of doing things:

***Create a protocol, that your cells would all adopt, like this:***

```
protocol UserDataPresentable {
    var nameLabel: UILabel? { get set }
    var surnameLabel: UILabel? { get set }
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UserDataPresentable {
    var nameLabel: UILabel?
    var surnameLabel: UILabel?
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if let cell = cell as? UserDataPresentable {
            cell.nameLabel?.text = "John"
            cell.surnameLabel?.text = "Doe"
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

***Create a custom parent and subclass it:***

```
class UserPresentableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var nameLabel: UILabel?
    var surnameLabel: UILabel?
}

class FriendCell: UserPresentableCell {
//    ...
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendCell", for: indexPath)

        if let cell = cell as? UserPresentableCell {
            cell.nameLabel?.text = "John"
            cell.surnameLabel?.text = "Doe"
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

BTW, check out that article to [avoid strings as identifiers](https://medium.com/idap-group/swift-conventions-are-good-strings-are-bad-6fdf53cf1991)

And do use the [cocoapod IDPCastable](https://github.com/idapgroup/IDPCastable).

No matter, which way you choose (protocols or subclassing), the ultimate target goal would look like that with IDPCastable:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellType = (indexPath.row % 2) == 0 ? FriendCell.self : UserCell.self
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withType: cellType, for: indexPath)

    return match(cell) { (c: UserPresentableCell) in
        c.nameLabel?.text = "John"
        c.surnameLabel?.text = "Doe"
    }
}
```

I'd pick subclassing in your case, btw, in order to avoid duplicating properties on different UITableViewCell subclasses.